# How to slice an objects property value in return method?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I make requests to an API that returns dates in the following format:

`dateProperty: "2019-07-16T00:00:00.000Z"`

I populate an `<input type="date">` element in one of my forms with this data, however it does not work since it does not read the timestamp bit, and I don't really need it.

Is it possible to slice out the timestamp bit within JSX or should I do that when I make the `GET` request? The response is an array of objects all having a `dateProperty`. Thanks

For example:

`<input type="date" value={object.dateProperty.slice(0,9)}`

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? It should work fine. Just be aware that timezone `Z` means UTC, so the actual date could very well be different from the user's location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `render` function, before `return`, assign the result of `slice ()` to another variable and use that:

```
render(){
  let formattedDate = object.dateProperty.slice(0,9);
  return (
    <input type="date" value={formattedDate}/>
  )
}
```

**Edit:**  For an array of objects you can simply include the code inside the `.map()`

```
render(){
  let formattedDate;
  return (
    {objects.map(object => {
       formattedDate = object.dateProperty.slice(0,9);
       return (<input type="date" value={formattedDate}/>)
    })}        
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have an array of objects that I loop through with `objects.map()` and not just one. How can I slice throught an array of objects in the same fashion and remove the timestamps?

Comment: I will edit my answer to show you how its done, but remember that ideally you would either supply the full and exact information in the original question, or if you haven't done that, ask another question for help on another problem. It will save both yours and the answerer's time.